# Qt Designer - Qt 4.8.1

Tags: qt, installation, pyqt4, qt-designer

I cannot figure out how to open up Qt Designer on MacOS. I am a new user to macOS and would greatly appreciate any help on how to open Qt Designer. I have already installed the Qt 4.8.1 libraries. It's not located in 'Applications' as I would have expected it to be when looking in Finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the details of the installer output - Qt does not install itself in the application folder but inside your personal documents, ~/QtSDK/... or something like that. I simply installed Qt twice as I did not find the Qt binaries inside the application folder and looked for the detailed installation report to figure out where the binaries went.

Comment: You're reffering to QtSDK package, but still on Mac OS X you can get single .dmg file with Qt frameworks and tools. If Ryan used standalone dmg it may be in /Developer/Applications/Qt/ directory

Comment: Thank you Kamil for the insight. I was able to find it!